# Flutter - change body according to the screen

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

[Homescreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D640z.png)

I want when one of the logos is clicked, that the models of exactly this brand are shown, currently I got just so far to show the [models of the first brand].[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hylg9.png)
So no matter which screen you click, always that appears. How can I change my code, that the specific brand models appear?

I only posted the crucial code, here Im navigating to the page ,,Model Page" (but I think its not relevant, because Im guessing that the problematic lays in the displaying of the body (2nd code)

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_meineapp/Indexes/Marken.dart';
import 'package:flutter_meineapp/Screen/Home/BodyHomescreen.dart';
import 'package:flutter_meineapp/Screen/Kontakt/Kontakt.dart';
import 'package:flutter_meineapp/Screen/Modelle/Modelle.dart';


class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeScreenState createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  int _selectedIndex = 0;
  List<Widget> _widgetOptions = <Widget> [
    Container(
      color: Color(0xffDDBEA9),
      child: GridView.builder(
        itemCount: modelle.length,
        gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
          crossAxisCount: 2,
          ),
        itemBuilder: (context,index) =>
            BodyHomescreen(
              modell: modelle[index], press: () => Navigator.push(
                context, MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) => Modelle( modell: modelle[index],)
              ,)
            ),
            ),
      ),
    ),
    Text("Text2"),
    Kontakt()
  ];
```

And here is the model page, Im guessing that I somehow need to change the body according to the Index, but after my research I couldn't find a solution, any suggestions?

```
    class Modelle extends StatelessWidget {
  final Modell modell;

  const Modelle({Key key, this.modell}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        actions: [
          Container(
            width: 50,
            child: Image.asset(modell.image),
          ),
        ],
        title: Text(modell.title),
        centerTitle: true,
        backgroundColor: Color(0xffCB997E),
      ),
      body: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: ModelleAlfaRomeo.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return ListTile(
            title: Text(ModelleAlfaRomeo[index].title),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
```

code for Class ,,Modell"

```
    class Modell {
  final String image, title;
  final int id;
  Modell({
    this.image,
    this.title,
    this.id,
  });
}

List<Modell> modelle = [
  Modell(
    id: 1,
    title: "Alfa Romeo",
    image: "Assets/Images/AlfaRomeo.png"
  ),
  Modell(
      id: 2,
      title: "Audi",
      image: "Assets/Images/Audi.png"
  ),
  Modell(
      id: 3,
      title: "BMW",
      image: "Assets/Images/BMW.png"
  ),
  Modell(
      id: 4,
      title: "Chevrolet",
      image: "Assets/Images/Chevrolet.png"
  ),
  Modell(
      id: 5,
      title: "Citroen",
      image: "Assets/Images/Citroen.png"
  ),
  Modell(
      id: 6,
      title: "Dacia",
      image: "Assets/Images/Dacia.png"
  ),
  Modell(
      id: 7,
      title: "Fiat",
      image: "Assets/Images/Fiat.png"
  ),
  Modell(
      id: 8,
      title: "Ford",
      image: "Assets/Images/Ford.png"
  ),
  Modell(
      id: 9,
      title: "Honda",
      image: "Assets/Images/Honda.png"
  ),
  Modell(
      id: 10,
      title: "Hyundai",
      image: "Assets/Images/Hyundai.png"
  ),
  Modell(
      id: 11,
      title: "Jaguar",
      image: "Assets/Images/Jaguar.png"
  ),
  Modell(
      id: 12,
      title: "Jeep",
      image: "Assets/Images/Jeep.png"
  ),
  Modell(
      id: 13,
      title: "KIA",
      image: "Assets/Images/KIA.png"
  ),
  Modell(
      id: 14,
      title: "LandRover",
      image: "Assets/Images/LandRover.png"
  ),
  Modell(
      id: 15,
      title: "Lexus",
      image: "Assets/Images/Lexus.png"
  ),
  Modell(
      id: 16,
      title: "Mazda",
      image: "Assets/Images/Mazda.png"
  ),
  Modell(
      id: 17,
      title: "Mercedes",
      image: "Assets/Images/Mercedes.png"
  ),
  Modell(
      id: 18,
      title: "Mini",
      image: "Assets/Images/Mini.png"
  ),
  Modell(
      id: 19,
      title: "Mitsubishi",
      image: "Assets/Images/Mitsubishi.png"
  ),
  Modell(
      id: 20,
      title: "Nissan",
      image: "Assets/Images/Nissan.png"
  ),
  Modell(
      id: 21,
      title: "Opel",
      image: "Assets/Images/Opel.png"
  ),
  Modell(
      id: 22,
      title: "Peugeot",
      image: "Assets/Images/Peugeot.png"
  ),
  Modell(
      id: 23,
      title: "Porsche",
      image: "Assets/Images/Porsche.png"
  ),
  Modell(
      id: 24,
      title: "Renault",
      image: "Assets/Images/Renault.png"
  ),
  Modell(
      id: 25,
      title: "Saab",
      image: "Assets/Images/Saab.png"
  ),
  Modell(
      id: 26,
      title: "Seat",
      image: "Assets/Images/Seat.png"
  ),
  Modell(
      id: 27,
      title: "Skoda",
      image: "Assets/Images/Skoda.png"
  ),
  Modell(
      id: 28,
      title: "Smart",
      image: "Assets/Images/Smart.png"
  ),
  Modell(
      id: 29,
      title: "Subaru",
      image: "Assets/Images/Subaru.png"
  ),
  Modell(
      id: 30,
      title: "Suzuki",
      image: "Assets/Images/Suzuki.png"
  ),
  Modell(
      id: 31,
      title: "Toyota",
      image: "Assets/Images/Toyota.png"
  ),
  Modell(
      id: 32,
      title: "Volvo",
      image: "Assets/Images/Volvo.png"
  ),
  Modell(
      id: 33,
      title: "VW",
      image: "Assets/Images/VW.png"
  ),
];
```

code for class ModelleAlfaRomeo -> is exactly structured as all the other classes that depict the models of the car brands

```
    class ModellAlfaRomeo {
  final String title;
  final int id;
  ModellAlfaRomeo({
    this.title,
    this.id,
  });
}
List<ModellAlfaRomeo> ModelleAlfaRomeo = [
  ModellAlfaRomeo(
    id: 1,
    title: "147" ,
  ),
  ModellAlfaRomeo(
    id: 2,
    title: "156 / Crosswagon Q4" ,
  ),
  ModellAlfaRomeo(
    id: 3,
    title: "159" ,
  ),
  ModellAlfaRomeo(
    id: 4,
    title: "166" ,
  ),
  ModellAlfaRomeo(
    id: 5,
    title: "4c" ,
  ),
  ModellAlfaRomeo(
    id: 6,
    title: "Brera" ,
  ),
  ModellAlfaRomeo(
    id: 7,
    title: "GT" ,
  ),
  ModellAlfaRomeo(
    id: 8,
    title: "Giulia (Typ 952)" ,
  ),
  ModellAlfaRomeo(
    id: 9,
    title: "Giulietta (Typ 940)" ,
  ),
  ModellAlfaRomeo(
    id: 10,
    title: "MiTo" ,
  ),
  ModellAlfaRomeo(
    id: 11,
    title: "Spider" ,
  ),
  ModellAlfaRomeo(
    id: 12,
    title: "Stelvio" ,
  ),
];
```

tried today to embed the code from all the classes like ModelleAlfaRomeo, ModelleChevrolet, in this ,,Modell" class, don't really know how to do it yet

Comment: what is modelle? Where have you defined it?

Comment: its a class, that contains a list with all the models of all the car brands (with id, foto & name). Im right now trying to get all the model details of each brand in this list, right now all the car brand models are in separate classes, for example contains the class ModelleAlfaRomeo a list of titles of all the alfa Romeo car models. Could you follow my explanation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how you would architect your classes:

```dart
/// model.dart
import 'model_make.dart';

class Model {
  final int id;
  final String title;
  final String image;
  final List<ModelMakeData> modelData;

  Model({
    required this.image,
    required this.title,
    required this.id,
    required this.modelData,
  });

/// Create your models on the fly
List<Model> models = [
  // AlphaRomeo model
  Model(
    id: 1,
    title: "AlphaRomeo",
    image: "Assets/Images/AlfaRomeo.png",
    modelData : <ModelMakeData>[
      ModelMakeData(
        id: 1,
        title: "147" ,
      ),
      ModelMakeData(
        id: 2,
        title: "156 / Crosswagon Q4",
      ),
      ModelMakeData(
        id: 3,
        title: "159",
      ),
      // other data go here....
    ]
  );
  // Audi model
  Model(
    id: 2,
    title: "Audi",
    image: "Assets/Images/Audi.png",
    modelData: <ModelMakeData>[
      // Audi's data go here ...
    ]
  );
  //other models go here ...
];
```

Create an other file to hold the model data

```dart
/// model_make.dart
class ModelMakeData{
  final int id;
  final String title;

  const ModelMakeData({
    required this.id,
    required this.title,
  })
}
```

To use the class in your widget you would do:

```dart
/// home_screen.dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_meineapp/Indexes/Marken.dart';
import 'package:flutter_meineapp/Screen/Home/BodyHomescreen.dart';
import 'package:flutter_meineapp/Screen/Kontakt/Kontakt.dart';
import 'package:flutter_meineapp/Screen/Modelle/Modelle.dart';//<--- update to point to model.dart


class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeScreenState createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  int _selectedIndex = 0;
  List<Widget> _widgetOptions = <Widget> [
    Container(
      color: Color(0xffDDBEA9),
      child: GridView.builder(
        itemCount: models.length,// <--- updated
        gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
          crossAxisCount: 2,
          ),
        itemBuilder: (context,index) =>
            BodyHomescreen(
              modell: models[index], press: () => Navigator.push(
                context, MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) => Modelle( modell: models[index],)
              ,)
            ),
            ),
      ),
    ),
    Text("Text2"),
    Kontakt()
  ];
```

And in the Modelle widget you do:

```dart
class Modelle extends StatelessWidget {
  final Model modell;

  const Modelle({Key key, this.modell}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        actions: [
          Container(
            width: 50,
            child: Image.asset(modell.image),
          ),
        ],
        title: Text(modell.title),
        centerTitle: true,
        backgroundColor: Color(0xffCB997E),
      ),
      body: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: modell.modelData.length,// <--- now you are getting modelData!
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return ListTile(
            title: Text(modell.modelData[index].title), // <--- Updated
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
```

> *Note*
> Although this solution is OK. I would recommend creating a json file where you store all of your static data and use `json_annotation` along with `json_serializable` to generate your class form it. You can read more about this [here](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/json)
> Your json file would look something like:
>
> ```json
> // cars json data
> [
>  {
>    "id":1,
>    "title": "Alfa Rome",
>    "image": "Assets/Images/AlfaRomeo.png",
>    "modelData":[
>      {
>        "id": 1,
>        "title": "147" ,
>      }
>      {
>        "id": 2,
>        "title": "156 / Crosswagon Q4" ,
>      }
>      {
>        "id": 3,
>        "title": "159" ,
>      }
>    ],
>  },
>  {
>    "id":2,
>    "title": "Audi",
>    "image": "Assets/Images/Audi.png",
>    "modelData":[
>      {
>        "id": 1,
>        "title":
>      }
>      //whatever list of data you have for audi
>    ],
>  }
> ]
> ```

Comment: thank you really much for your efforts! If I cleaned my data according to that, how can I now change the body if I klick on a certain brand, so if I for example klick on Audi a list of all the Audi models shows up, and not how its right now, that only AlfaRomeo is depicted

Comment: you're welcome. I think the way is it now it should show the list of each model data upon model button click!

Comment: sorry didn't see that, do I need the json_to_model 1.4.0 package to import the model_make.dart part?

Comment: Nope, you are not ;) keep up the good energy

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code you are not using the model you're passing down to the `Modelle` widget! you are always referring to the same `ModelleAlfaRomeo`  model. That's why you are getting the same view!

Not user how's your model structured but the below update could help

```dart
  class Modelle extends StatelessWidget {
  final Modell modell;

  const Modelle({Key key, this.modell}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        actions: [
          Container(
            width: 50,
            child: Image.asset(modell.image),
          ),
        ],
        title: Text(modell.title),
        centerTitle: true,
        backgroundColor: Color(0xffCB997E),
      ),
      body: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: medell.length, //<---- Update this  
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return ListTile(
            title: Text(modell.title), // <---- Update this
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: First of all thanks for ur help, but I was looking for something different. Maybe I didn't ask the question correctly, I want that if I tap on a certain brand, that ModelleAlfaRomeo, is replaced by the correct brand, for example if I press on Chevrolet, everything should stay the same, just ModelleAlfaRomeo, should become ModellChevrolet, I already defined everything, but I don't know how to make them change, do you understand me?

Comment: What is ModelleAlfaRomeo??? an abstract class?
You could add it a property in your Modell class. So that you could access it like:
Modell.make.length and Modell.make.title

Comment: I just defined it as a simple class, like the Modell class (this name is misleading -> I should change it, it is responsible for the brands that u see on the first screen). In each class which shows the models of the brand is a list of the all the models(as objects) that belong to the brand. So I have the class ModellAlfaRomeo, which contains a list with all the models of this brand, a class ModellChevrolet, which contains a list with all the models of this brand and so on. Do you get it? I can send u more detailed screenshots if u want

Answer (score 0):

You can use the LayoutBuilder widget.

Reference: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/LayoutBuilder-class.html

Comment: didn't really get it, how?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67286438/flutter-change-body-according-to-the-screen/70692671#70692671

Answer (score 0):

You could create a Map<int, dynamic>

````dart
Map<int, dynamic> modelData = {
0: ModellAlfaRomeo,
1: ModelAudi,
...
}
The get the moddell data based on the index
```dart 
print(modelData[0]); // => ModellAflaRomeo
print(modelData[1]); // => ModellAudi
````

> **Note**
> This is not considered to be a good practice since it will be hard to
> maintain. You should remember what index corresponds to what
> modelData.
> Rather, I recommend you store the modelData in the Modell class itself so that you can access it through an instance rather than looking for it in a map!:

---

here the code for the classes -> Modell & ModellAlfaRomeo

```
    class Modell {
  final String image, title;
  final int id;
  Modell({
    this.image,
    this.title,
    this.id,
  });
}

List<Modell> modelle = [
  Modell(
    id: 1,
    title: "Alfa Romeo",
    image: "Assets/Images/AlfaRomeo.png"
  ),
  Modell(
      id: 2,
      title: "Audi",
      image: "Assets/Images/Audi.png"
  ),
  Modell(
      id: 3,
      title: "BMW",
      image: "Assets/Images/BMW.png"
  ),
  Modell(
      id: 4,
      title: "Chevrolet",
      image: "Assets/Images/Chevrolet.png"
  ),
  Modell(
      id: 5,
      title: "Citroen",
      image: "Assets/Images/Citroen.png"
  ),
  Modell(
      id: 6,
      title: "Dacia",
      image: "Assets/Images/Dacia.png"
  ),
  Modell(
      id: 7,
      title: "Fiat",
      image: "Assets/Images/Fiat.png"
  ),
  Modell(
      id: 8,
      title: "Ford",
      image: "Assets/Images/Ford.png"
  ),
  Modell(
      id: 9,
      title: "Honda",
      image: "Assets/Images/Honda.png"
  ),
  Modell(
      id: 10,
      title: "Hyundai",
      image: "Assets/Images/Hyundai.png"
  ),
  Modell(
      id: 11,
      title: "Jaguar",
      image: "Assets/Images/Jaguar.png"
  ),
  Modell(
      id: 12,
      title: "Jeep",
      image: "Assets/Images/Jeep.png"
  ),
  Modell(
      id: 13,
      title: "KIA",
      image: "Assets/Images/KIA.png"
  ),
  Modell(
      id: 14,
      title: "LandRover",
      image: "Assets/Images/LandRover.png"
  ),
  Modell(
      id: 15,
      title: "Lexus",
      image: "Assets/Images/Lexus.png"
  ),
  Modell(
      id: 16,
      title: "Mazda",
      image: "Assets/Images/Mazda.png"
  ),
  Modell(
      id: 17,
      title: "Mercedes",
      image: "Assets/Images/Mercedes.png"
  ),
  Modell(
      id: 18,
      title: "Mini",
      image: "Assets/Images/Mini.png"
  ),
  Modell(
      id: 19,
      title: "Mitsubishi",
      image: "Assets/Images/Mitsubishi.png"
  ),
  Modell(
      id: 20,
      title: "Nissan",
      image: "Assets/Images/Nissan.png"
  ),
  Modell(
      id: 21,
      title: "Opel",
      image: "Assets/Images/Opel.png"
  ),
  Modell(
      id: 22,
      title: "Peugeot",
      image: "Assets/Images/Peugeot.png"
  ),
  Modell(
      id: 23,
      title: "Porsche",
      image: "Assets/Images/Porsche.png"
  ),
  Modell(
      id: 24,
      title: "Renault",
      image: "Assets/Images/Renault.png"
  ),
  Modell(
      id: 25,
      title: "Saab",
      image: "Assets/Images/Saab.png"
  ),
  Modell(
      id: 26,
      title: "Seat",
      image: "Assets/Images/Seat.png"
  ),
  Modell(
      id: 27,
      title: "Skoda",
      image: "Assets/Images/Skoda.png"
  ),
  Modell(
      id: 28,
      title: "Smart",
      image: "Assets/Images/Smart.png"
  ),
  Modell(
      id: 29,
      title: "Subaru",
      image: "Assets/Images/Subaru.png"
  ),
  Modell(
      id: 30,
      title: "Suzuki",
      image: "Assets/Images/Suzuki.png"
  ),
  Modell(
      id: 31,
      title: "Toyota",
      image: "Assets/Images/Toyota.png"
  ),
  Modell(
      id: 32,
      title: "Volvo",
      image: "Assets/Images/Volvo.png"
  ),
  Modell(
      id: 33,
      title: "VW",
      image: "Assets/Images/VW.png"
  ),
];
```

2. 

```
    class ModellAlfaRomeo {
  final String title;
  final int id;
  ModellAlfaRomeo({
    this.title,
    this.id,
  });
}
List<ModellAlfaRomeo> ModelleAlfaRomeo = [
  ModellAlfaRomeo(
    id: 1,
    title: "147" ,
  ),
  ModellAlfaRomeo(
    id: 2,
    title: "156 / Crosswagon Q4" ,
  ),
  ModellAlfaRomeo(
    id: 3,
    title: "159" ,
  ),
  ModellAlfaRomeo(
    id: 4,
    title: "166" ,
  ),
  ModellAlfaRomeo(
    id: 5,
    title: "4c" ,
  ),
  ModellAlfaRomeo(
    id: 6,
    title: "Brera" ,
  ),
  ModellAlfaRomeo(
    id: 7,
    title: "GT" ,
  ),
  ModellAlfaRomeo(
    id: 8,
    title: "Giulia (Typ 952)" ,
  ),
  ModellAlfaRomeo(
    id: 9,
    title: "Giulietta (Typ 940)" ,
  ),
  ModellAlfaRomeo(
    id: 10,
    title: "MiTo" ,
  ),
  ModellAlfaRomeo(
    id: 11,
    title: "Spider" ,
  ),
  ModellAlfaRomeo(
    id: 12,
    title: "Stelvio" ,
  ),
];
```

Comment: So should I do like a nested class (Im not sure if you can do one in dart [I know how to do it in Python] or something similar to this)? And I should then be able to access the data, through CarBrands.SpecificModell[index].title ?

Comment: yes, embedding class would def help. Can you share the code where you define your classes? it will be of great help

Comment: That made things a bit clear. I have posted a new answer based on that. I hope it will help you solve the issue ;)

Answer (score 0):

Use Responsive widget from [nb_utils](https://pub.dev/packages/nb_utils). Just import this package and use it.

here is the code example. You can change your widget based on the mobile, tablet, or web screen size.

```
Responsive(
  mobile: MobileWidget(),
  tablet: TabletWidget(),
  web: WebWidget(),
),
```

For more information, you can reply to this thread or contact me.